# How can I get my CPU Utilization Down? PYGAME PROJECT

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pygame

I get 25% CPU usage on this simple project. I hope it's okay if I just post the whole thing. It probably something to do with the rendering code. It's definitely the project though, my fans get loud, then I exit the program, and quiet again.

```
#python3 -OO main.py
import pygame
import json
import sys
import os

#OS
xMax = 800
yMax = 640
xWin = 1366 - xMax #pins window to top right of the display
yWin = 0
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" % (xWin, yWin)

#PYGAME
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Mountain of Doom")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((xMax, yMax))
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)

with open('saves/save.json') as save_file:
    data = json.load(save_file)
    
tileSize = 16
tile_images = {
    1: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/grass.png"),
    #ABOUT 10 MORE CALLS
}

with open("resources/maps/demo.json", "r") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    tileMap = json_data["tileMap"]

class Background:
    def __init__(self, tile_images, tileSize, tileMap):
        self.tile_images = tile_images
        self.tileSize = tileSize
        self.tileMap = tileMap

    def draw(self, screen):
        background = pygame.Surface((len(self.tileMap[0]) * self.tileSize, len(self.tileMap) * self.tileSize))
        for row in range(len(self.tileMap)):
            for col in range(len(self.tileMap[0])):
                tile_id = self.tileMap[row][col]
                if tile_id in self.tile_images:
                    tile_image = self.tile_images[tile_id]
                    background.blit(tile_image, (col * self.tileSize, row * self.tileSize))
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

class Player:
    def __init__(self, position, player_path):
        self.position = position
        self.image = pygame.image.load(player_path)
        self.speed = 16
        
    def move(self, keys):
        x, y = self.position
        speed = self.speed
        
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 0:
            y -= speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y += speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
            x -= speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += speed
        self.position = (x, y)
   
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.position))
        
def update_data(player):
    data['player_x'] = player.position[0]
    data['player_y'] = player.position[1]
    with open('saves/save.json', 'w') as save_file:
        json.dump(data, save_file)
        
def main():
    background = Background(tile_images, tileSize, tileMap)
    player_path = "resources/graphics/sprites/player1.png"
    position = (data['player_x'], data['player_y'])
    player = Player(position, player_path)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        mbreak = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                mbreak = True
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            mbreak = True
        background.draw(screen)
        player.move(keys)
        player.draw(screen)

        text = f'{player.position[0]}, {player.position[1]}'
        img = font.render(text, True, (0xFFFFFFFF))
        screen.blit(img, (20, 20))
      
        pygame.display.update()
        if mbreak:
            break
        
    update_data(player)
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To help reviewers give you better answers, we need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*.  Please add sufficient context to your question to describe the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  Also, [edit] the **title** to simply [**summarise the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: What hardware?  What fraction of a CPU core does it occupy when running, according to your OS's process monitoring tools, e.g. `top` on Linux?  IDK if it's worth profiling it with `perf record` to see if there's a lot of CPU time spent in a shared library (such as a graphics lib).  Also, if your X server uses a lot of CPU time while this is running, that could also be a thing.  Do you have proper graphics drivers for your video hardware set up?

Comment: Did you write this game? Posting the whole game is fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes I get 25% CPU usage on my i5-4200M. I don't have a GPU.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I did. Is it okay if I post a download link (discord)?

Comment: External links are not up for review. Links can rot.

Comment: If your laptop gets hot, consider cleaning out the fans and the rest of it.

Comment: i5-4200M has an integrated GPU, Intel® HD Graphics 4600.  It's not very powerful, but it supports OpenGL and stuff so it's much more than a dumb framebuffer.  Even on Linux the drivers should be set up automatically since they're open source.  When you say 25% CPU usage, are you on Windows which reports CPU load as a fraction of the total logical cores?  So "25%" of your 2c4t CPU is all of one logical core, i.e. your program running as fast as the CPU + GPU is able to run it, not sleeping to wait for input or for time until the next frame.

Comment: JSON serialization can also be slow. Comment it out and see how much faster your ptogram becomes.

Comment: (For a given "computation", I can see the advantage of low energy consumption, of low wall-clock time. What would be the advantage of reduced *CPU utilisation*?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FROM:

```
tile_images = {
    1: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/grass.png"),
    2: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/water.png"),
    3: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/tree.png").,
    4: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/bones.png"),
    5: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/rocks.png"),
    6: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/brick1.png"),
    7: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/brick2.png"),
    8: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/tree2.png")
}
```

TO:

```
 tile_images = {
        1: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/grass.png").convert_alpha(),
        2: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/water.png").convert_alpha(),
        3: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/tree.png").convert_alpha(),
        4: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/bones.png").convert_alpha(),
        5: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/rocks.png").convert_alpha(),
        6: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/brick1.png").convert_alpha(),
        7: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/brick2.png").convert_alpha(),
        8: pygame.image.load("resources/graphics/sprites/tree2.png").convert_alpha()
    }
```

This got my CPU usage down from 25%-26% to 7%-8%.

Answer (score 11):

The code is not easy to run because I don't have your local files. However, I was able to throw some together in MS Paint. Although I didn't notice any performance issues (you might need to update your packages?), I think that the main issue is that you are repeatedly computing the background Surface in your Background class. Personally, I would just put together the background once and then blit it for each drawing animation. You also might want some input validation.

```
class Background:
    def __init__(self, tile_images, tile_size, tile_map):
        """
        Creates a background image and makes it easy to draw.

        :param tile_images: from tile_id to source
        :param tile_size: positive integer number of pixels
        :param tile_map: 2D array from (row, col) to tile_id
        """
        if tile_size < 1:
            raise ValueError("Tile size less than 1 pixel!")
        n_rows = len(tile_map)
        if n_rows < 1:
            raise ValueError("Less than 1 map row!")
        n_cols = len(tile_map[0])
        if n_cols < 1:
            raise ValueError("Less than 1 map col!")

        background = pygame.Surface((n_cols * tile_size, n_rows * tile_size))
        for row in range(n_rows):
            for col in range(n_cols):
                tile_id = tile_map[row][col]
                tile_image = tile_images[tile_id]
                background.blit(tile_image, (col * tile_size, row * tile_size))

        self.background = background

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
```

That change reduced the CPU utilization from an average of 2.5% to an average of 0.5% for me. Hope that helps. Welcome to the community.

Comment: This is what jumped out at me as well.  Creating objects in a tight loop in pygame (and they're _all_ tight loops) is a red flag. Ideally do all your object creation at init-time.